# the convergence of a double sequences of random variables

Tags: probability

We put $\mbox{LL}n=\log\log n$ for  $n\geqslant 4,\mbox{LL}n=1$ for  n=1,2,3. For $n\geqslant1,a_n=(2n\mbox{LL}n)^{1/2}$

We have known that:

Let $\{X_j\}$ be independent,identically distributed r.v.'s with $\mathbb{E}|X_1|^2<\infty.$Let $\tau>0$,and difine $\widetilde{X_j}=X_jI\{|X_j|>\tau(j/\mbox{LL}j)^{1/2}\},U_n=\sum_{j=1}^nZ_j.$Then
$$\frac{U_n}{a_n}\rightarrow 0 \quad a.s..$$

But now I have a problem:

Let $\{X_{n,j},n\geqslant1,j\geqslant1\}$be independent,identically distributed r.v.'s with $\mathbb{E}|X_{1,1}|^2<\infty.$Let$\tau>0,$and difinte~
$\widetilde{X_{n,j}}=X_{n,j}I\{|X_{n,j}|>\tau(j/\mbox{LL}j)^{1/2}\},
U_{n,k}=\sum_{j=1}^k\widetilde{X_{n,j}}$.$\{Z_n,n\geqslant1\}$is a sequence of random variables which take values in positive intergers and converges almost surely to infty,then can we have
$$\frac{U_{n,Z_n}}{a_{Z_n}}\rightarrow0\quad a.s.?$$